# Multiplication "speed"

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

If I have nested multiplications:

$\left((a+b)(c+d)+(e+f)(g+h)\right)\left((i+j)(k+l)+(m+n)(o+p)\right)$

How long does it take to multiply out and collect terms? - Suppose there are at most $n$ "layers". Is this problem in P? - Can it be computed in polynomial time?

- I am just starting to learn about computational complexity and I do not know some of the formal names so hopefully nested and "layers" make sense.

Thanks for any help, Ben

Comment: Are you looking for the complexity of obtaining the $16$-term polynomial, or its value for specific $a,\,\cdots,\,o$? A computer wouldn't do the latter by multiplying out.

Comment: I'm interested in 2 steps. Firstly, the full expansion. Then how long it takes to collect terms. I'm curious to know if both are in P.

Comment: You don't provide enough explanations to "generalize to $n$ layers".

Comment: As written, this expression has a number of additions and multiplications linear in the number of variables. Expanded, these numbers are rather exponential.

Comment: In short, it's terms within factors within terms within factors... Each term and factor pairing being 1 layer.

Comment: What do you mean by "collect terms" here? If you multiply out, you end up with 64 _different_ monomial terms, and nothing to "collect".

Comment: @HenningMakholm This particular example is definitely in P then. (Slight overlook on my part) I was wondering if collecting terms in elementary algebra is computable in polynomial time.

Comment: I don't think so. As @J.G. said, the number of terms in the result grows _exponentially_ with the size of the original tree -- or if not exactly exponentially, then at least faster than polynomially; my back-of-the-envelope estimates say it ought to grow as $2^{\sqrt k}$ for inputs of size $k$.

Comment: If latecomers are confused by differing term counts, $a+b$ was once $ab$ etc.